# scale animation in UITableViewCell interferes with scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I've created a sample repo demonstrating the issue:

https://github.com/dementrock/ScrollAnimationTest/commit/8ec61e24cdfa298e8eaee8c303f847c07809e35b

When building against the initial commit, you can see that very often, when you scroll down and then try to scroll up right after, the scrollview ignores the scroll up touch events until it decelerates. Removing the scale animations on the red blocks will solve this issue.

In the second commit (https://github.com/dementrock/ScrollAnimationTest/commit/c870b3900dbe5f95b81e469e53ba9a0df8100fdc), I fixed this issue by setting userInteractionEnabled to be NO on the red blocks. However, I don't know why this would fix the issue, and I don't know why the scaling animations would interfere with the scrolling. Can anyone give me a hint?

[Update 1]
The issue exists both in the simulator (iOS SDK 8.2) and on a real device (iPhone 5s, iOS 8.2)

A screenshot:

[image: screenshot]